# iphone 6 banner messing up after adding iphone 6 launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, iphone-6

So in my app i have my launch screen/splash screen set for the 4, 4s, 5, and 6+....basically all the splash screens except for the one for the 6.

Everything looks great. background images for the toolbar are properly scaled and everything. however on the iphone 6 its status bar is black even though its set in the plist to white and i believe it has to do with the missing iphone splash screen.

[image]

So I add in the launch screen for the 6 to correct this right? Awesome it works! but now my background image for the 6 doesnt get scaled properly and its left at the iphone 5 @2x size with a repeated edge.

[image]

How do i correct this?

Heres the code im using to implement the background image:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64);
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Missions.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

and here are my image names:

```
missions.png         (320x64)
missions@2x.png      (640x128)
missions@3x.png      (1242x195)
```

Notice i dont really have an image for the iphone 6 (750xwhatever).  thats because i dont see how i could fit it in the naming convention with how the code runs it. wish it were as easy as missions@2.5x.png.....

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just paste this into your UIViewController subclass

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

and go into your info.plist and add the key UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance and set it to YES.